# Add a gesture recognizer to tableView header doesn't work?

Tags: ios, ios5, uigesturerecognizer

I know that a "table view header"(the most top-part of a table view) is a View
So I try to add a UITapGestureRecognizer to it ,but it doesn't work...

code is simple :

```
- (void)tap:(UITapGestureRecognizer *)recognizer
{
    // do something
}

UITapGestureRecognizer *recognizer = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc]    initWithTarget:self action:@selector(tap:)];
[self.tableView.tableHeaderView addGestureRecognizer:recognizer];
```

Any tips here to care ? thanks a lot

Comment: Do you call it in init or in viewDidLoad or in other places?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's the thing that works for me:
Instead adding this:

```
self.tableView.tableHeaderView
```

I add gesture recognizer on every UILabel on tableview.

```
    -(UIView*)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section
{

    UILabel *headerLabel = [[UILabel alloc]init];
    headerLabel.tag = section;
    headerLabel.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
    headerLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor greenColor];
    headerLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Header No.%d",section];
    headerLabel.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, tableView.tableHeaderView.frame.size.width, tableView.tableHeaderView.frame.size.height);


    UITapGestureRecognizer *tapGesture = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc]initWithTarget:self action:@selector(catchHeaderGesture:)];
    tapGesture.cancelsTouchesInView = NO;
    [headerLabel addGestureRecognizer:tapGesture];

    return headerLabel;

    //return nil;
}

-(void)catchHeaderGesture:(UIGestureRecognizer*)sender
{
    UILabel *caughtLabel = (UILabel*)sender.view;

    NSLog(@"header no : %d", caughtLabel.tag);
}
```

I hope that helps.

Comment: `tableView.tableHeaderView` isn't the same as `viewForHeaderInSection:`

Comment: As long as you use `obj.userInteractionEnabled = YES`, then it should work. I use it with `tableView.tableHeaderView`

Answer (score 3):

First of all 
Make sure that you call this code section in viewDidLoad or viewWillAppear

```
UITapGestureRecognizer *recognizer = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc]    initWithTarget:self action:@selector(tap:)];
[self.tableView.tableHeaderView addGestureRecognizer:recognizer];
```

Second, please make sure that

```
self.tableView.tableHeaderView
```

is not null, add

```
NSLog([self.tableView.tableHeaderView description]);
```

And check the console for output

I just tried your code and the tap was recieved correctly

Comment: Thank you, My tableView head view is a "UILabel". I add the "NSLog([self.tableView.tableHeaderView description]);" to my code , it doesn't work still....But I find that in the console , there's something like "userInteractionEnabled = NO" . then I add a line of code to that label："label.userInteractionEnabled = YES" ,finally it works !!  do you know the reason ? :-)

Comment: @joshz:  It is because user interaction on UILabel is disable by default.

Comment: Also true for uiimageview