# Pass index tapping UITableViewHeader

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I want to get index when tap on `UITableView` header. Now I did add `UIGestureRecognizer` to header like that:

```
- (nullable UIView *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section {

    UITapGestureRecognizer *recognizer = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(sectionTapped:)];

    UIView *headerView = [UIView new];
    headerView.backgroundColor = [UIColor grayColor];

    [headerView addGestureRecognizer:recognizer];

   // return [self.myTableView headerWithTitle:self.headers[section] totalRows:self.cells.count inSection:section];
    return headerView;
}

-(IBAction)sectionTapped:(id)sender{

    NSLog(@"tapped header");
}
```

Is there are easy way to pass section `Index` on tap?

Comment: is your gesuture is works

Answer (score 2, accepted):

set tag for your `headerview` like `headerView.tag = section;`

```
  - (nullable UIView *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section {

    UITapGestureRecognizer *recognizer = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(sectionTapped:)];

    UIView *headerView = [UIView new];
    headerView.tag = section;
    headerView.backgroundColor = [UIColor grayColor];

    [headerView addGestureRecognizer:recognizer];

   // return [self.myTableView headerWithTitle:self.headers[section] totalRows:self.cells.count inSection:section];
    return headerView;
   }

 -(IBAction)sectionTapped:(UITapGestureRecognizer *)recognizer{

    NSLog(@"tapped header==%d",recognizer.view.tag);
    NSLog(@"tapped header == %ld", recognizer.view.tag);
}
```

**Swift 3 and above**

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, viewForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> UIView? {
let recognizer = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: Selector("sectionTapped:"))
let headerView = UIView()
headerView.tag = section
headerView.backgroundColor = UIColor.gray
headerView.addGestureRecognizer(recognizer)
// return [self.myTableView headerWithTitle:self.headers[section] totalRows:self.cells.count inSection:section];
return headerView
}

@IBAction func sectionTapped(_ recognizer: UITapGestureRecognizer) {
print("tapped header==\(recognizer.view?.tag)")
print("tapped header == \(recognizer.view?.tag)")
}
```

for alternate see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10861669/add-a-gesture-recognizer-to-tableview-header-doesnt-work)

Comment: `NSLog(@"tapped header==%@",recognizer.view.tag);` will trow exception, because tag is NSInteger.

Answer (score 1):

Add tag:

```
recognizer.view.tag = section;
```

and get:

```
- (IBAction)sectionTapped:(UITapGestureRecognizer *)recognizer{
    NSLog(@"tapped header %d", recognizer.view.tag);
}
```